# Qt 4 - QuaZip - File size limitation and memory issue

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, nokia, quazip

I use Qt 4 to build a Symbian Application.

The app use [Quazip](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/) library to unzip a file. It's work well if the file size under 13mb.

But if the file size larger than 13mb. it cannot unzip.

Is there any memory issue or file size limitation in [QuaZip](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/) Library and Symbian Qt 4 ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share how you use Quazip with Symbian. It would be helpful for some of us. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

QuaZIP access files inside ZIP archives using QIODevice API.

Based on your implementation choice i.e. the memory required by the concrete QIODevice subclass you use (QTextStream, QDataStream, QTcpSocket ...) you may run out of memory in environment where memory size is an issue.